# Teradata Rank Over Query (Getting one row to left join)

Tags: sql, left-join, teradata

Hi am new to Teradata and am stuck with a problem

There is an ID table which stores an Unique ID given to each person

```
CREATE TABLE IDS(
ID VARCHAR(8),
UPDATED_DATE DATE)
```

Then we have a name and address table which do not have any primary keys that stores demographic information for the IDS

```
CREATE TABLE NAMES(
ID VARCHAR(8),
NAME VARCHAR(50))
CREATE TABLE ADRRESSES(
ID VARCHAR(8)
ADDRESS VARCHAR(200))
```

Now each ID can have multiple name and IDS. However for names and address I want to use the ones that are have more counts. If two names have the same COUNT I just want the First row

ID              NAME                COUNT

1234    John Smith  6

1234    Johnnie Smith   6

1234    J Smith     2

In the above example I want the name John Smith. Here is the left Join I am performing since an ID may not have a name or address. Here is what I am trying

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT ID as V_ID from IDS) a
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT ID, NAME, COUNT(*) AS COUNTER,(RANK() OVER(ORDER BY COUNTER DESC)) AS RNK
FROM NAMES 
GROUP BY ID)b
ON a.ID = b.ID
AND b.RNK = 1            -- Should give me only the first row
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT ID, ADDRESS, COUNT(*) AS COUNTER, (RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNTER DESC) ) AS RNK
FROM ADDRESSES
GROUP BY ID) c
ON c.ID = a.ID
And c.RNK = 1
```

However this is not getting me the desired result. I tried using ROW NUMBER instead of RANK also but still no results. How should I write this query in TERDATA?

Comment: I'm a little confused by your syntax.  In most databases, the window functions (such as rank) cannot be used with group by.  I think you want to do the group by in a subquery and then the rank, or vice versa.

Comment: its allowed in teradata without needing a subquery. And the qury by itself `SELECT ID, ADDRESS, COUNT(*) AS COUNTER, (RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNTER DESC) ) AS RNK
FROM ADDRESSES
GROUP BY ID` works fine and gives the desired result so I doubt there is anything wrong with that

Comment: Is the count supposed to count the number of times an ID/name combination appears in the table (which presumably also has more columns in real life)? Can you also explain why John Smith is chosen ahead of Johnnie Smith when they have the same count?

Comment: @lins314159 if two counts are same its ok to choose any one of them so we can choose the first one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it ...I needed a `qualify` and a `partition by`

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT ID as V_ID from IDS) a
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT ID, NAME, COUNT(*) AS COUNTER
    FROM NAMES
    GROUP BY ID
    qualify ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY COUNTER DESC) = 1
    )b
    ON a.ID = b.ID
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT ID, ADDRESS, COUNT(*) AS COUNTER
    FROM ADDRESSES
    GROUP BY ID
    qualify ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY COUNTER DESC) = 1
    ) c
    ON c.ID = a.ID
```